# Python using set to make unique list items not working

Tags: python

```
import random

player_cards = []


card_list = ("Hearts", "Diamonds", "Spades", "Clubs")

while len(player_cards) != 44:
    i = random.randint(1, 11)
    j = random.choice(card_list)
    player_cards.append("%s of %s"%(i, j))
    set(player_cards)
    if len(player_cards) == 44:
        print(player_cards)
```

I want the code to add a card to the `player_cards` list then check to see if the same card already exists and remove it if it does. Set is not working.

Edit: I'm only creating the entire deck this way instead of using shuffle to properly test the removing of duplicates.

Comment: You make a set but not assigning back to itself (so it flies away). Besides, converting list to set in every iteration is quite expensive. Why not make an empty set in the first place and just `player_cards.add`?

Comment: generate your list of cards, then shuffle it https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle. It will be more simple

Answer (score 1):

`set(player_cards)` creates a set from the supplied iterable.

You can write this to get a unique list, but the order will have changed.

`player_cards = list(set(player_cards))`

I don't know if the rest of your code is sensitive to that change of order.  But as others have said, this is an inefficient way to ensure uniqueness, for two reasons: (1) the conversions to and from `set`, and (2) the need to repeat until you have 44 unique cards, with decreasing probability as the list fills up.

Comment: Given it depends on `append` being a method, and only make sense if order is maintained, the code would definitely break, and likely be logically incorrect.

Comment: Ah, yes - I did not look closely enough (thanks). I added a conversion back to list. I'm not seeing the ordering requirement though, given the random choice.

Comment: @J.Backus The random choice suggests a random order requirement.

Comment: Oh, I see your point now - set produces an arbitrary but predictable (not random) order. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the struck through solution, it won't produce a proper randomized ordering (`set`s can't preserve the random order). Leaving it only because it explains the original problem.

<s>You made a `set` and didn't assign it to anything, so it just got thrown away. You need to use it or store it for it to mean anything. Seems like you really want it to be a `set` from the get go:</s>

```
import random

player_cards = set()

card_list = ("Hearts", "Diamonds", "Spades", "Clubs")

while len(player_cards) != 44:
    i = random.randint(1, 11)
    j = random.choice(card_list)
    player_cards.add("%s of %s"%(i, j))
    if len(player_cards) == 44:
        print(player_cards)
```

That said, this just produces the 44 unique cards in a semi-randomized order (but not properly shuffled; it'll vary from run to run due to string hash randomization, but that's an implementation detail you shouldn't rely on), by the most inefficient means possible (you'd likely generate hundreds of cards before you finished), and probably doesn't meet your requirements. There's a much simpler solution for randomizing your deck: Make the complete `list` of cards, then shuffle it:

```
from itertools import product

player_cards = ["%s of %s"%(i, j) for i, j in product(range(1, 11), ("Hearts", "Diamonds", "Spades", "Clubs"))]
random.shuffle(player_cards)
```

That's it; randomized in fixed time, no constant checking for duplicates.

Comment: I'm randomising the entire deck this way for the purposes of testing so I can remove all duplicates.

Comment: @CyrilJouve: Yeah, the `set` approach won't work as written (but neither would their original approach in any reasonable way). The `random.shuffle` approach is the correct solution.